# Response data in json fromat of two tables with mapping using phalcon

Tags: json, phalcon

I am trying to get response of the data in json format of two tables user and project where they are related in  hasMany(users) and belongsto(project).I want json response in the same object according to the mapped data How can I do this without using the query builder or phql code?

This is a PhalconPhp micro application used as api running on Apache or localhost

```
    //..Service-start..//
    <?php 
    namespace App\Services;
    use App\Models\User;    
        public function getUserList()
        {
            try 
            {
                $users = User::find (
                    [
                        'conditions' => '',
                        'bind'       => [],
                        'columns'    => "id, first_name, last_name, login",
                    ]
                );
          //How to include the project data in same $users variables without using query builder// 
                if (!$users) 
                {
                    return [];
                }

                return $users->toArray();

            } 
            catch (\PDOException $e) 
            {
                throw new ServiceException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
            }
        }
    //..Controller-end..//

    //..Project Model-start..//
    <?php
    namespace App\Models;
    class Project extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
    {

        /**
         *
         * @var integer
         */
        public $id;

        /**
         *
         * @var integer
         */
        public $user_id;

        /**
         *
         * @var string
         */
        public $p_name;

        /**
         *
         * @var string
         */
        public $p_desc;

        /**
         * Initialize method for model.
         */
        public function initialize()
        {
            $this->setSchema("topic");
            $this->setSource("project");
            $this->belongsTo('user_id', 'App\Models\User', 'id', ['alias' => 'User']);
        }

        /**
         * Returns table name mapped in the model.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getSource()
        {
            return 'project';
        }

        /**
         * Allows to query a set of records that match the specified conditions
         *
         * @param mixed $parameters
         * @return Project[]|Project|\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\ResultSetInterface
         */
        public static function find($parameters = null)
        {
            return parent::find($parameters);
        }

        /**
         * Allows to query the first record that match the specified conditions
         *
         * @param mixed $parameters
         * @return Project|\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\ResultInterface
         */
        public static function findFirst($parameters = null)
        {
            return parent::findFirst($parameters);
        }

    }
    //..Project Model-end..//

    //..User Model-start..//

    <?php
    namespace App\Models;
    //use App\Models\Project;
    class User extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
    {

        /**
         *
         * @var integer
         */
        public $id;

        /**
         *
         * @var string
         */
        public $first_name;

        public $last_name;

        /**
         *
         * @var string
         */
        public $pass;

        /**
         *
         * @var integer
         */
        public $login;

        /**
         * Initialize method for model.
         */
        public function initialize()
        {
            $this->setSchema("topic");
            $this->setSource("user");
            $this->hasMany("id", "App\Models\Project", "user_id", array(
                'alias' => 'projects'
              ));
        }

        /**
         * Returns table name mapped in the model.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getSource()
        {
            return 'user';
        }

        /**
         * Allows to query a set of records that match the specified conditions
         *
         * @param mixed $parameters
         * @return User[]|User|\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\ResultSetInterface
         */
        public static function find($parameters = null)
        {
            return parent::find($parameters);
        }

        /**
         * Allows to query the first record that match the specified conditions
         *
         * @param mixed $parameters
         * @return User|\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\ResultInterface
         */
        public static function findFirst($parameters = null)
        {
            return parent::findFirst($parameters);
        }

    }

    //..User Model-end..//

    The expected output should be :
      [  {
            "id": "2",
            "first_name": "Nametest",
            "last_name": "Sourtest",
            "login": "0",
            "projects":    [{
            "id": "1",
            "p_name": "Project1",
            "p_desc": "testing",
            "user_id": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "p_name": "Project2",
            "p_desc": "testing2",
            "user_id": "2"
        }]
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "first_name": "Nametest1",
            "last_name": "Sourtest",
            "login": "0",
            "projects":    [{
            "id": "3",
            "p_name": "Project123",
            "p_desc": "testing123",
            "user_id": "3"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "p_name": "Project234",
            "p_desc": "testing234",
            "user_id": "3"
        }]
        }
    ]

    The output I am getting now is just users how to write the code to include projects in the same object:
    [{
            "id": "2",
            "first_name": "Nametest",
            "last_name": "Sourtest",
            "login": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "first_name": "Nametest1",
            "last_name": "Sourtest",
            "login": "0"
        }]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options:

#### Manipulate arrays

Get the users array, get the project array, merge them in a loop, return the data back. This will definitely hurt performance, using more memory. Note that this implementation introduces the infamous N+1 issue i.e. you are introducing a query inside the loop, hitting the database more than required.

```php
$data     = [];
$users    = Users::find(
    [
        'columns' => 'id, first_name, last_name, login'
    ]
);

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $record = $user->toArray();
    $projects = Projects::find(
        [
            'conditions' => 'user_id = :user_id:',
            'bind'       => [
                'user_id' => $user->id,
             ]
        ]
    );

    // now add the projects to the record
    $record['projects'] = $projects->toArray();

    // Add the record to the final array
    $data[] = $record;
}
```

#### Using relationships

Easier to work with but still suffers from the N+1 issue

```php
$data     = [];
$users    = Users::find(
    [
        'columns' => 'id, first_name, last_name, login'
    ]
);

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $record = $user->toArray();
    $projects = $user->getRelated('projects');

    // now add the projects to the record
    $record['projects'] = $projects->toArray();

    // Add the record to the final array
    $data[] = $record;
}
```

#### Using the builder

I realize that you mentioned that you don't want to use the builder, but consider it since it offers the best performance for your needs

```php
$results = (new Builder())
    ->addFrom(Users::class, 'u')
    ->leftJoin(Projects::class, 'p')
    ->columns(
        [
            'u_id'       => 'u.id',
            'first_name' => 'u.first_name',
            'last_name'  => 'u.last_name',
            'login'      => 'u.login',
            'p_id'       => 'p.id',
            'p_name'     => 'p_name',
            'p_desc'     => 'p_desc',
        ]
    )
    ->orderBy('u.last_name, u.first_name, p.p_name')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute()
;

$data = [];
foreach ($results as $record) {
    $data[$results->u_id] = [
        'id'         => $record->id,
        'first_name' => $record->first_name,
        'last_name'  => $record->last_name,
        'login'      => $record->login,
        'projects'[$result->p_id] => [
            'id'     => $result->p_id,
            'p_name' => $result->p_name,
            'p_desc' => $result->p_desc,
        ],
    ];
}

return $data;
```

**Note** The code above is for demonstration, I have not tested it, so you might want to adjust it according to your needs

Comment: Thank you Nikolaos Dimopoulos it helped to slove the issue